# Will window.onload fire after XHR request

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

My use case is to load third-party libraries after the backend APIs are fetched. So that this will help us to optimize website performance.

At present, I load third-party libraries when `window.onload` fires.

So I search for when will `window.onload` triggers and I found that few people said "`window.onload` fires when the whole page has loaded, including all dependent resources such as stylesheets and images". Here I didn't understand what are the **dependent resources**? Will **XHR requests** also come under **dependent resources**?

If `window.onload` fires before XHR requests how can I load third-party libraries?

Comment: It just means all the elements in the HTML, like `<link rel="stylesheet">` It doesn't wait for anything that's loaded dynamically with XHR.

Comment: What do you mean under `execute third party-librares`? Include them with  `<script>` tag?

Answer (score 0):

No, an XHR is not a dependent resource. Its resolution will not result in `load` firing.

If you want to do something like call an external library or few after a request is done, put the call(s) in the callback of the request:

```js
function reqListener () {
  console.log(this.responseText);
}

const r = new XMLHttpRequest();
r.addEventListener("load", () => {
  console.log('request done');
  console.log('call libraries here');
});
r.open("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
r.send();
```

If you have multiple requests you want to make first, I'd suggest using `fetch` and `Promise.all` to wait for all of them to finish first:

```js
const makeReq = url => fetch(url).then(res => res.json());
Promise.all([
  makeReq('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1'),
  makeReq('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/2'),
])
  .then(() => {
    console.log('requests done');
    console.log('call libraries here');
  });
  // .catch(handleErrors);
```